# auditctl doesn't stores reads

Tags: linux, permissions, audit, auditd

So I have this rule on auditctl:

```
-w /home/ec2-user/myfile -p rwa -k key-name
```

But when I run

```
ausearch -f /home/ec2-user/myfile
```

or check the logs in /var/log/audit/audit.log, I can't see any reading record for that file, even when I am running cat, grep, vi, nano, against the file (even opened for reading in python). If I do a write/append change though, auditd will log it.
Is there any other way to know what process is reading from a particular file?

Answer (score 0):

The above commands listed in your question do work as expected on a system where auditd/selinux is active. Tested on Fedora 33.

Is auditd installed and running on your system?